# How to plot spatial data in Python with axis in DMS format?

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio, matplotlib

I have a plot that displays a raster file and shapefiles with the axes shown in lat/lon. Is there an option to change the axis to DMS instead?

```
coastline = gpd.read_file('.shp')
coords = gpd.read_file('.shp')
raster = rasterio.open('.tif')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
rasterio.plot.show(raster, ax=ax)
coastline.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black',legend=True)
coords.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none',edgecolor='red',linewidth=1.3)
ax.set_ylim([lat1, lat2])
ax.set_xlim([lon1, lon2])

image_hidden = ax.imshow(raster.read()[0])
cbar=fig.colorbar(image_hidden, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Is your problem that lat/lon are in decimal degrees vs. DMS?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is divide de decimal part of min part of the coord by 60 and the second by 3600.
eg: 10°15'45.2"

```
d, m, s = coord_text.replace("°","'").replace("\"", "'").split("'")
d = float(d)
m = float(m)/60
s = float(s)/3600
coord = d + m + s
```

Do this for each axis and after that you have decimal values.

Comment: This plots on a decimal degrees axis. The OP asked how to plot in DMS.

Comment: to plot DMS they need to transform to decimal degree